# Will a buyer be able to restore my personal data from my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, deletion

I want to sell my iPhone but it has lots of personal data on it. Apple suggests to *[Erase All Content and Settings](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201351#:%7E:text=Go%20back%20to%20Settings%20and%20tap%20General%20%3E%20Transfer%20or%20Reset%20%5Bdevice%5D%20%3E%20Erase%20All%20Content%20and%20Settings.)* before selling an iPhone. Is this enough to reliably delete all data or will it be recoverable for a tech-savvy buyer?